# Extending LoginUtil in Liferay 6.2 hook

Tags: authentication, hook, liferay-6

we are migrating from 5.2 to liferay6.2.

There is our custom LoginUtil class which is extending  com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil in the ext-plugin of 5.2 version.

I have to rewrite this as a hook .What are my options? Is there a LoginUtil service or are there any LoginUtil classes in other packages other than portal-impl in the 6.2 version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `LoginUtil` in 5.2. But if your objective is to implement custom Login logic then you can look at `com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AutoLogin` . You will have to write a hook and set the following property
`auto.login.hooks=`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.I need to extend com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil to overwrite logout() functionality.I have to do this in liferay6.2 hook.Since I cant have portal-impl.jar in the classpath ,this is throwing compilation error.Want to know if I can extend any other class in other packages to achieve LoginUtil functionality.  Thanks